# Get top average ratings using mongoosejs statics

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I just started learning mongoosejs. I have come across a compleated example

Here I have a collection schema named Movies. Example document looks like below.

```
{
    "title": "Movie title",
    "year": "1920",
    "type": "movie",
    "images": ["url/of/image1", "url/of/image2" ...],
    "ratings" : [
       {"comment" : "user1 comment", "rating" : 3.2}, 
       {"comment" : "user2 comment", "rating" : 4}, 
       {"comment" : "user3 comment", "rating" : 5}, 
       {"comment" : "user4 comment", "rating" : 2}, 
       ....
    ]
  }
```

I want to get the **top 10 movies** with the **highest rating**. It should consider only movies that have **at least 10 ratings**. How can I do this sort of operation using mongoosejs statics

Answer (score 1):

An aggregation can do the job easily,

https://mongoplayground.net/p/OfTebk9vr6A

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "ratings.9.rating": {
                $gte: 0
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$ratings"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$title",
            avgRating: {
                $avg: "$ratings.rating"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            avgRating: -1
        }
    },
    { $limit: 10 }
])
```

Consider having an index for the above query as well ("ratings.9.rating" will avoid counting the size of the array and consume less cpu & memory usage rather than using $size)

```
db.collection.createIndex({"ratings.9.rating"});
```